# Why does my Firefox authentication popup only offer one username/password combination?

Tags: firefox, password-management, popups, authentication

I have two cPanel accounts at the same machine (shared hosting). I am connecting to cPanel with Firefox (3.5.3) on Mac (10.5.8).

I enter site IP in address bar and this basic authentication popup (`Authentication Required`) appears:

[image: Authentication Required]

Firefox remembered both usernames/passwords, but every time when I connect to the site, it only offers me one username/password (and always the same one), and there is no way I could select the other one (like I can on sites that have login page instead of basic authentication popup).

I am sure Firefox remembered both passwords, because I can see them in `Saved Passwords`.

[image: Saved Passwords]

Also, when I make the mistake while entering the other username/password, Firefox asks if I want to change the password for the other username, so I guess it knows it.

Is there a way I can get to the other username/password?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way to do what you want with the default Firefox setup. The pop-up authentication will only remember the most recent password, not giving you a drop-down like it does with in-page remembered passwords.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to check out some [password add-ons at Mozilla](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/search?sort=weeklydownloads&q=password&appid=1&cat=0%2C0&tag=&atype=-1&pid=-1&lup=&hver=any&lver=-1&vfuz=&pp=20).